# How do I validate all files in a torrent using libtorrent offline in python?

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent

Given a torrent file, I would like to use libtorrent to validate that I have all the files, essentially what a *force recheck* would do in a bittorrent client, and I want to do it off-line and without involving some other client.

I've only found how to recalculate the hash for all pieces but I'm not quite sure how to use it if I already *have* everything and just want to make sure it matches what's already available on disk.

Here's a short example of what I would like to accomplish:

```py
import libtorrent as lt
torrent = lt.load_torrent_file("torrents/legal_linux_iso.torrent")
torrent.save_path = 'data/'
if torrent.recheck():      # Mythical missing part
    print("Hurrah!")
```

I'm worried that if I try implementing code that calculate every piece, I will end up missing some detail with regards to version 1 or 2, hybrid torrent files, merkle trees and such. Hopefully there's a short and robust solution I've missed. Also, I want to use *libtorrent* for this because it's used for other things in my code and the client I'm working with, so if there's any quirks I want the quirks to at least match!

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag called `stop_when_ready` (see [documentation](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#torrent_flags_t)) which will prevent the torrent from initiating any downloading.

Comment: I guess that functionality isn't exposed. This is not meant to do any networking at all but I guess I could create a new torrent with `set_piece_hashes()` and compare them.

Comment: what functionality is not exposed? and what do you mean by "exposed"?